# Is possible build an iPhone project from mac os x terminal and without an xcode project?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, terminal

is possible build an iPhone project from Mac os x terminal and without an xcode project?
I'd like to make an iPhone static library without create and using xcode project and only with the terminal.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For subsequent builds, after the first one, you can look at the command lines that Xcode executes in its Build window (there's a little command disclosure tab) and copy all those command lines into a script or suitable makefile template.

Comment: For an app, you'll also need to generate Entitlements.xcent (for code-signing) and Info.plist, pick the correct provisioning profile, and do code-signing. A static library should be pretty easy though.